# ICollection circular reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a LINQ query like so

```
var Data = from a in db.Medlem
                   where a.Person.PersonId.Equals(BrukerCv.Person.PersonId)
                   select new
                   {
                       a.Prosjekt.ProsjektId,
                       a.Prosjekt.Navn,
                       a.Prosjekt.Kunde,
                       a.Prosjekt.TekniskProfil,
                       a.MedlemId,
                       a.Rolle,
                       a.Start,
                       a.Slutt
                   };
```

and I want to return it like a json, so I use this

```
return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but the problem I encountered is that I get the error

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CVVersjon_4F0DBDC27A40F2FDF90760ABFDE49CBE0B75F52902B1C5F1E466393543AC44E8'.

Which I suppose is because of the `a.Prosjekt.TekniskProfil` which is an `ICollection`

So how can I get the ICollection?

Like, I don't want all the values in the ICollection TekniskProfil, just certain values

There's a reference in the `TekniskProfil` table back to the `Prosjekt` table, which is what I don't want I am guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select only the values you need when projecting the data:

```
select new
{
    ProsjektId = a.Prosjekt.ProsjektId,
    Navn = a.Prosjekt.Navn,
    Kunde = a.Prosjekt.Kunde,
    TekniskProfil = a.Prosjekt.TekniskProfil.Select(x => new
    {
        // Select only the properties you need here and avoid
        // circular references - exclude all properties that contain
        // circular object graphs
        Foo = x.Foo,
        Bar = x.Bar,
    }),
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is most likely that a.Prosjekt.TekniskProfil contains objects, where that object contains a reference to a medlem.
During the serialisation, it is then detected that the medlem is in fact already being serialised and hence you get the error.

The projection solution provided by Darin solves this issue, but I think it is nice to know why you get this error too.

I don't speak your language, so it is a bit hard to infer what is going on. But whenever I got this error, it was that during serialisation it somehow finds it way back to an object that is being serialised in the first place. If the serialisation where to continue, it would be an endless loop.